# Is it possible to set multiple type to a variable?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, data-types

Consider this

```
f[x_Real] := 2 x
```

> ```
> f[1]
> ```
>
> f[1]
>
> ```
> f[1.0]
> ```
>
> 2.0

I want `f` to be evaluated if `x` is an integer or real. One way can be define it twice

```
f[x_Real] := 2 x
f[x_Integer] := 2 x
```

which might not be a good idea while dealing with big functions with several variables.

Is it possible to assign multiple type (for example `Real` and `Integer`) to a single variable in a function?

Comment: Or if you want to evaluate for all numeric inputs `f[x_?NumericQ]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may specify multiple alternative patterns (originally mentioned in a comment):

```
f[x:(_Real|_Integer)] := 2 x;
```

You may specify multiple alternative matches simultaneously:

```
f[(x_Real|x_Integer)] := 2 x;
```

You may specify by set-membership tests (`Element`):

```
f[x_?(Element[#, Reals] === True &)] := 2 x;
```

Note, however, that while this option will work for exceptional cases like `f[Sqrt[2]]`, is also likely going to be quite a bit slower than any of the above.

If you are concerned not with membership in the reals but rather numeric quantities, you may use:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := 2 x;
```

Note, however, that this will allow complex quantities. This is frequently used to prevent excessive symbolic computation with difficult functions implemented inside of other complex operations, such as `Integrate`.